# (date_time_selector) return in moodle

Tags: php, moodle

Does any one know if it is possible to have datetimepicker from date_time_selector function in moodle?  I want the date/time selected from date_time_selector in a variable to store it into the database.

This is the code what I am working on right now in my edit.php , what am I missing

require_once('../../config.php');

require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/course/lib.php');

require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/blocks/myblcok/myblock_form.php');

global $DB;

```
require_login($SITE);

$block = new myblock();

$mform = new myblock_form();




if ($data  = $mform->get_data()) {


    $startdate = $data->startdate;
}




    $dataobject = new stdClass;
    $dataobject->name = get_string('entryname', 'myblock');
    $dataobject->description = get_string('entrydescription',
                                           'myblock');
    $dataobject->course = $COURSE->id;
    $dataobject->userid = $USER->id;
    $dataobject->starttime = $data->date;
    $DB->insert_record('event', $dataobject);
redirect($CFG->wwwroot.'/course/view.php?id='.$courseid, '', 0);
```

Comment: Does anybody has any suggestion for my question?

Comment: I am having an error with  'A required parameter (courseid) was missing' when a button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming this is being used in a form? The return value from data_time_selector is a timestamp which can be stored in a database. eg:

In edit_form.php file

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/lib/formslib.php');

class edit_form extends moodleform {

    function definition () {

        $mform =& $this->_form;

        $mform->addElement('date_time_selector', 'mytime', get_string('mytime', 'mycomponent'));

    }
}
```

In edit.php

```
require_once('edit_form.php');

$mform = new edit_form();

if ($data = $mform->get_data()) {
    // This is a timestamp.
    $mytime = $data->mytime;
}
```

EDIT:

Ah... you need to pass a data object to insert a record eg:

```
$newrecord = new StdClass();
$newrecord->mytime = $mytime;
$DB->insert_record('table', $newrecord);
```

Or if the form field names are the same as your field names, just use the $data object eg:

```
$DB->insert_record('table', $data);
```

Have a look through the database API :

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Inserting_Records

Comment: I used the code above and try to insert into the database using the following code, but nothing is happening.$DB->insert_record('table',  $mytime);

Comment: one question I have is , should the 'table' must be an existing one in moodle database or I can create my own table? Because I didn't get the result yet, so I am assuming maybe the table name is the problem.

Comment: Yes 'table' is just an example name. You will need to use an existing table or create your own. If want to create your own then you should use the XMLDB editor with your plugin - http://docs.moodle.org/dev/XMLDB_editor

Comment: No probs :) Can you mark my answer as correct/up vote? Thanks, Russ

Comment: I have edited my code, where I am working on right now. do   u have any suggestion about it.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you read through the whole of the Database API - http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API - and the Form API - http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Form_API - you should be using $DB->update_record('event', $dataobject) but after $form->get_data() - also read through how to create a block  http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks